# C# Calling variables from a class and assigning to a list

Tags: c#, list, class

I'd like to know a way to assign variables in a class to a list in another class. I've got the following code so

```
public class Names
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var playerNames = new List<Names>();
       playerNames = getPlayerList(ref totalPlayers);
       //??
    }
}
```

`totalPlayers` is a user input integer from another section of code.

`getPlayerList` is a section of code where it asks the user to input some names and then that's assigned to the `Name`' in `Names` class using a `for` loop.

Everything works so far, I'd just like to know how to assign the variables in `Name` of the `Names` class to a list in `Main`.

Right now I'm assigning all the variables to strings and then adding those strings to a list but that ends up in a lot of wasteful code.

```
string player1 = playerNames[0].Name, player2 = playerNames[1].Name;
// and so on
List<string> players = new List<string>();
players.Add(player1); 
players.Add(player2); // and so on
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a [loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx) is?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of answer you need. The obvious answer is `players.AddRange(playerNames.Select(p => p.Name));`, which will copy the `Name` property values as individual object references to the `players` list. But, you didn't provide a good [mcve] showing real code, and it's not really clear what exactly is the difficulty you're having. Giving you a working line of code isn't necessarily what you want or need. Please clarify your question and improve it. See also [ask] for advice on presenting your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Your code won't compile - what is `totalPlayers`? If you are assigning `playerNames` to the result of calling `getPlayerList`, you don't need to create a new, empty `List` when you declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to create the list:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var players = getPlayerList(ref totalPlayers);
    var playerNames = players.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
}
```

Otherwise you would loop through your `List`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var players = getPlayerList(ref totalPlayers);
    var playerNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var p in players)
        playerNames.Add(p.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate through your list.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
   var playerNames = new List<Names>(); 
   //I assume that getPlayerList() is a function that will populate your list with objects of type Names
   playerNames = getPlayerList( ref totalPlayers );

   //you can iterate through the entire list of objects and retrieve whatever properties you need 
    foreach ( var p in players )
    {
       Console.WriteLine( "Id " + p.Id );
       Console.WriteLine( "Name " + p.Name );
    }

    //Or create just a list of names using the Name property on 'Names'
    var listOfNames = new list<string>();
    foreach ( var p in players )
    {
       //and populate using the Name property from each 'Names' item
       //in your list
       listOfNames.add( p.Name );
    }

    //This Will print the first index in the list
    Console.WriteLine( listOfNames[0] );
}
```

However it would be cleaner to use `linq` here as NetMage has already pointed out.

---

### Update

When you say

> getPlayerList is a section of code where it asks the user to input
>   some names and then that's assigned to the 'Name' in 'Names' class
>   using a for loop.

Why not use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) for this instead of a list of Names? It looks like all you want to do is store a name `(string)` alongside a unique Id `(int)`.

```
Dictionary<int, string> playerNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
playerNames,add( 0, "John Smith" );
playerNames,add( 1, "Wil Wheaton" );
playerNames,add( 2, "Jon Skeet" );
```

Then you just need to iterate through the dictionary instead

```
foreach( var p in playerNames )
{
   Console.WriteLine( "Id " + p.Key );
   Console.WriteLine( "Name " + p.Value );
}
```

A dictionary would be a **lot** quicker to search through if you find yourself with a lot of users and you know their exact id's.

Comment: It's for an assignment and using a class is required and I couldn't think of any other place to use a class. But thanks, that's definitely helpful and I'll keep that in mind for other coding projects.